# AngularJS Directive that sets CSS flickers on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a directive that prevents a fixed position DIV from floating over a footer DIV, what happens is when the user scrolls we determine the position of the bottom of the fixed DIV from the top of the footer (with a 10px space) and then apply a CSS style if the condition is true and we remove the style if the condition is false, see below...

```
return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element) {

                var page = angular.element(window);

                page.bind('scroll resize', function () {
                    var elementScrollBottom = element[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom,
                        footerTop = document.getElementById('footerTop').getBoundingClientRect().top;


                    if (elementScrollBottom + 10 >= footerTop) {
                        element.css({'bottom': (page[0].innerHeight - footerTop) + 10 + 'px'}) ;
                    } else {
                        element.removeAttr('style');
                    }

                });

            }
        }
```

This is simple stuff and works great however when the condition is true and we apply the style my div in the HTML view (that has the directive applied to it) flickers like crazy whilst scrolling and sometimes due to the crazy flickering the position of the DIV will be wrong once the scrolling is complete (this is only in extreme cases). Does anyone know how I can remove the issue with the flickering? I've also noticed that the dynamic css rule seems to be removed when the fixed DIV (the div with the directive applied to it) is at the top of the window... this increases the flickering.

My HTML for the directive looks like so (minus the comments regards computerized css):

```
<!-- the parent has the following CSS rules -->
<!--
    width: 260px;
    max-width: 260px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 150;
-->

<div class="pull-right">  
    <!-- the child div with directive has the following CSS rules --> 
    <!--
    position: fixed;
    width: 260px;
    -->
    <div data-my-directive-name>
        Lots of Content here!!!!
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mike, I've a feeling that the `if..else` is triggered there with a result that you are describing, maybe do a console.log in both to check it

Comment: I have noticed that the flickering is caused when the top of the div with the directive hits the top of the window (especially on ios bounce). That is what is creating the issue?

Comment: It looks like it for me when the elements are clashing and it goes in triggers the `if..else` several times assigning bottom and then removing style and again and again, I think that more fixed solution would be best for you, I could answer more precisely if you can provide working plunker or jsfiddle

Comment: Here is the code http://plnkr.co/edit/UhimBv?p=info - it doesn't seem so bad here...

Comment: It flickers like hell for me if i scroll to bottom and then scroll back, I've did console.log in if and else and it looks like what I expected, if-else-if-else-if is called over and over, working on a fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a small flow in logic, when you scroll down it's fine because the if statement will be true, but once you scroll up the difference in position between elements will grow, that's when the style attribute is removed, and then triggered again since flowing div gets back to original position in which it overlaps, here is a working plunker with answer to your problem,

notice the `if (elementScrollBottom + (page[0].innerHeight - footerTop) + 10 >= footerTop) {`

http://plnkr.co/edit/cvPNoF?p=preview

Comment: You absolute Genuius! I just didn't spot that. Thanks!